# odd results from nested for loops javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I'm trying to check a submitted string against a letterset. If `word_string = "GAR"`, this should return `"GAR"` because these letters appear in letterset.

For some reason, some words appear correctly, and some appear with missing letters. For example, with `word_string = "RAG"`, this returns `"R"`. `"FIG"` returns `"FG"`.

```
letterset = {0: "R", 1: "A", 2: "G", 3: "A", 4: "O", 5: "E", 6: "F", 7: "I"}


    var ls = [];
    for (prop in letterset) {
        ls.push(letterset[prop]);

    };
    console.log(ls)
    var word_string = '';
    var word = document
               .getElementById('word_container')
               .childNodes;
    for (var i in word) {
        var w = word[i].innerHTML;

        for (var prop=0; prop<ls.length; prop++) {
            if (ls[prop] == w) {
                console.log(w);
                word_string += w;
                ls.splice(prop);

            } 
        }

}
```

Comment: Why isn't `letterset` an array? Why are you calling `.splice()` with only one argument, and have you thought about what happens if you remove elements from an array while you're iterating over that same array? What do you think that does to your for loop's indexing?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle that is working with the current example?

Comment: Because it's coming from a python backend as a json object

Comment: what is word? var word = document
               .getElementById('word_container')
               .childNodes;

Comment: word is the html element with the necessary string as its .innerHTML

Comment: can you print w, and see if you actually get all the letters in RAG and FiG?

Comment: @nnnnnn letterset is an array because it comes from a python backend as json, and removing elements in place was to eliminate duplicate letters, but your point is well taken. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81049/discussion-between-quantico-and-cameron-sima).

Comment: @nnnnnn deleting the .splice() line, this results in "RAAG" for word_string = "RAG". So there is some other complicating error somewhere

Comment: OK, I'll spell it out a little more: your inner loop is skipping elements in `ls`, because sometimes you delete the current element but still increment `prop` afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using splice incorrectly, regardless this is a bit over complicated try:

```
 for (var i in word) {
    var w = word[i].innerHTML;
    if (ls.indexOf(w)> -1) {
            word_string += w;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: FYI this ls.indexOf(w)> -1 is kind of like x in list in python.